# Improve numerical accuracy of LineLine intersection method (3D)

Tags: c++, math, precision, eigen

I coded the following LineLine intersection method:

```
double LineLineIntersection(
    const Eigen::Vector3d& origin1,
    const Eigen::Vector3d& ray1,
    const Eigen::Vector3d& origin2,
    const Eigen::Vector3d& ray2)
{
    if(abs((origin1 - origin2).norm() - 1.0) < 0.000001) return 0;
    auto n1 = (origin2 - origin1).cross(ray2);
    auto n2 = ray1.cross(ray2);

    // Use this to test whether the vectors point in the same or opposite directions
    auto n = n2.normalized();
    // If n2 is the 0 vector or if the cross products are not colinear, no solution exists
    if(n2.norm() < 0.00001 || abs(abs(n1.dot(n)) - n1.norm()) > 0.000001)
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();;

    return n1.dot(n) / n2.dot(n);
}
```

The theory for how this works is explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180927042445/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62814.html). However the page has a mistake, taking just the absolute value has only the magnitude, it erases the direction. So instead, the dot product with the cross direction must be taken. That way the distance can be either positive or negative depending on whether the vectors point in the same direction or not.

This technically works but I am running into big numerical errors. For example in one of my tests I am getting:

```
The difference between i1.x() and Eigen::Vector3d(-0.581, 1.232, 0).x() is 0.0024061184231309873, which exceeds 0.001, where
i1.x() evaluates to -0.58340611842313095,
Eigen::Vector3d(-0.581, 1.232, 0).x() evaluates to -0.58099999999999996, and
0.001 evaluates to 0.001.
```

An error bigger than 0.001 is huge. What can I do to make the method more accurate?

This is the value of `i1`: `-0.583406   1.23237         0` sorry to not have included it before.

Comment: What is i1? Where is it?

Comment: Why do you use norms?  You should consider using squared norms (dot product with self), you are wasting most of your cpu time computing square roots, that you only use for checking if there is indeed intersection.  That's quite a waste.  As for your question,  the error you are seeing probably comes from the square root in the computation of n, your normalized vector.   Maybe another approach for simply setting the sign of the result would give better results.

Comment: Huh interesting, I was always told that normalizing values has a tendency to increase numerical stability. But it's definitely worth checking. I will try and see.

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve], e.g. what is WindowEdgeIntersection?

Comment: My question does not lack a MVCE, the MVCE is the original piece of code at the top of the post. I provided the test because I kept getting downvoted and hoped more context would help. I was clearly wrong about that so I just removed it to prevent the post from being confusing.

Comment: Make your posts self-contained. Put what "theory" we need in the post. When you give a program with a bug, it needs to be minimal code shown to be correct minimally wrongly extended, with justification for what you instead expected. [mre] Here you don't justify that the result has any particular relationship to a "theoretical" answer. Here you must reason re floating point inputs & operations & show the result is close enough to the "theoretical" result. You need to follow a textbook on  "numerical methods"--floating point computation. Then write a justified program using your new knowledge.

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Pause work on the overall goal. Chop code to the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. Find the 1st point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what it is supposed to be. (Debugging fundamentals.) Say what you expect & why with justification per authoritative documentation. [ask]

Comment: @Makogan btw your reaction to feedback answers your meta question: instead of reading the provided link , looking at your question with information provided by the link in mind and improving it, so that people willing to spent time helping you have it as easy as possible to reproduce your problem. You choose to argue that your question is already ok. Alas, this is the usual reaction to such feedback - so is it really surprising that people choose to save their energy, downvote, closevote and move on without a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the type "double", try to change it to "long double" or "__float128" if it exists in your version of G++. Also, you can use "BigDecimal" in Java for better accuracy or maybe some long arithmetics from Python.

Comment: Although I appreciate the suggestion. I am stuck with working with doubles. Increasing the precision is not possible. I need rather, tricks you can leverage for example when working with quaternions you normalize the quaternion after each operation. I know that sometimes re stating the problem in different algebraic terms leads to less divisions / products etc which also improves accuracy. That's what I am looking for. Or a different algorithm that relies only in vector algebra.

Comment: You could multiply your numbers by some power of 10. Say, value -> value * 10^6. I know only how to normalize line: Ax + By + C = 0, take D = hypotl(A, B) and do A /= D, B /= D, C /= D, I doubt if it can be applied to parametric line formulas.

Comment: How does multiplying by a power of 10 improve precission? Honest question

Comment: There is a known problem with floating point arithmetics: (1e+200)+(1e-9) maybe equals to (1e+200) in storing (i.e. 1e-9 does not considered cause it's much smaller than 1e+200) and (1e-9)+(1e+200) maybe equals to it's true equivalent or vice versa. Anyways, the numbers in your test are pretty small and it looks like the code has some bugs or different issues.